# Twilio SMS Twiml with Test Credentials

Tags: testing, sms, twilio, credentials, twilio-twiml

I'm using twilio with the test credentials and I send a simple sms from the test number +15005550006 to my twilio number. When I execute it I get an sid. On my twilio number I have set up a request url to receive the twiml request but it never gets hit. I'm able to access that url from the internet (not localhost) myself but never when sending a test sms.

Since I am using test credentials, is twilio sending a request to my url? And is there a way to see from the twilio report/alert to see if it is actually trying to connect to that url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials) won't deliver any SMS messages. Think of it as having the ability to exercise any requests, but not actually making them for real. Test credentials are useful for developing if you're concerned about making API requests.

To get the messages delivered you will need to use you real credentials.

Let me know if you have any questions.